# pipe can not read/write all the chars

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, pipe, fork

I am trying to send array of char from one process to another using pipe, the characters are passing but not all of them! only the part of the beginning.
This is my code:

```
int p1[2], p2[2];

int main()
{
    pipe(p1);

    int f1= fork();

    if(f1 == 0)

    {       
        char ar[100];
        int n = 38;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        { ar[i] = 'f'; }
        close(p1[0]); //close the read
        write(p1[1],ar,n+1);

    } else if (f1 > 0)

    {
        wait(NULL);
        int f2 = fork();
        if(f2 == 0)

        {   
            char arr2[100];
            close(p1[1]); //close the write
            int m = read(p1[0],arr2,strlen(arr2));
            cout << arr2 << " " << m << endl;   

        } 
        else if (f2 > 0)

        {wait(NULL);}

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't terminate the "string" you send/receive. Also, if `read` fails (`m == -1`) then the contents of the buffer is unspecified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You invoke `std::strlen()` on an uninitialized `char` array, which is your mistake. `std::strlen()` looks for the first occurence of a null byte in the array and returns its position. But the array is **uninitialized**, thus making the first occurence of the null byte **undefined**.

Besides, you should check the return values of the library functions (`pipe()`, `read()`, `write()`, `fork()`, etc.).

Comment: so how can i pass the strlen()? i can't put constant, because in the actual program i am reading the characters from file

Comment: You could send it through the pipe first and store it.